# Cannot find include files from other .h files in eclipse CDT despite settings being correct

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I have a project which includes a 3rd party header.  That header includes other headers in other directories.  I have all these directories specified in the project's Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols (for all languages).

The file that it cannot find is right there in one of the include paths shown right in the project explorer!   See illustration below.   How can I make this work?  Note, from my source I can control-click a 3rd party header and get to it.  It just seems these headers cannot find the other headers.  I did try rearranging the order of the includes, to no avail.

[image]

Comment: If the compiler is `g++`, get the command line started by Eclipse and add `-H` there.

Comment: It's not clear from your picture where php.h resides.  The zend_API.h file is expected to be in the same directory as php.h though, since the double quote include notation is used.

Comment: @LMC it's at the top of the editor  - /usr/local/zend/include/php/main/php.h.   A different directory.  But also included.

Comment: Change `#include "zend_API.h"` to `#include "../Zend/zend_API.h"`

Comment: @LMC php.h is 3rd party code.  I suppose I could change it, but if XCode can figure it out, Eclipse CDT should be able to, as well!

Comment: This is not an Eclipse CDT issue.  It's the compiler (g++?) that is unable to find the .h file.  If you are unwilling to change php.h, then you should put the content of the php/Zend directory in php/main.  Or you can make the smaller change of the double quote include to bracket include.